# Angularjs : Unable to watch a variable in service and notify to controller : Possible 2 rootscopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to watch a value in my service from my controller. But the watch is not getting fired.

Here is my code

```
    Service.js

    (function() {
        function myService($rootScope, anotherService) {
            console.log(rootScope)
            this.myList = [];

            this.getListOfValues = function(question,questionType) {
            anotherService.getList(function(data, status) {                 
                        myService.myList = data;
                });                         
            }                           
        }
        app.addService(app.config.modules.MY_MODULE, "myService", myService);
    }());


    Controller.js

    (function() {
        function myCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
            console.log(rootScope)
            this.askQuestion = function() {
                myService.getListOfValues();
            }
            $scope.myService = myService;
            $scope.myList = myService.myList;

            $scope.$watch('myService.myList', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if(newVal && newVal.length > 0) { 
                    $scope.listToLoad = newVal;
                }
            });
            app.addController(app.config.modules.MY_MODULE, "myCtrl", myCtrl);
    }());


    home.html

    <html ng-app = "myApp">
        <head>
            <script>
                app.inject(app.config.modules.MY_MODULE, "myService", function(instance) {
                    myService = instance;
                    console.log("myService dependency injected successfully.");
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div>
                <img id="getList" onclick="askQuestion()">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

If myList variable changes in my service I want the changes to be notified to the controller, and the controller should take some action. But the watch is not firing. I tried to fire an event on change of myList using the $rootScope.emit() and then catching that event in my controller using $rootScope.on() but even that doesn't work.

When I log the value of rootScope in my service I see that the rootScope has an id 1. Please refer to the screenshot [image: click here]

And when I log the value of rootScope in my controller I see that the rootScope has an id 2. Please refer to the screenshot. [image: click here]

And if I check for the scope at the topmost level i.e.  html ng-app = "myApp" level I see that the scope has an id 2 which is same as the controller.

I do not understand why my controller and service have 2 different rootScope id's. Is this this the reason why my event or watch is not being fired?

Could someone please shed some light on this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular services are singletons within a single injector (app instance). `app.inject` creates a new injector which has its own set of service singletons.